# Save JSON Response as Variable to Deserialise with SwiftyJSON

Tags: json, swift3, alamofire

I'm going to use either SwiftyJSON or EasyFastMapping to deserialise JSON data into variables and constants but I'm not sure on how to save the whole JSON file into its own object, if it is even possible.

I will be using Alamofire to handle the GET request and pull the JSON data down, is it possible to do it like this?

How I want it to work:
1. Alamofire pulls down the JSON data

2. Alamofire puts the data into an object
3. SwiftyJSON accesses the downloaded data and allows me to put individual parts of the data into separate variables and constants.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could take a look at the documentation for [SwiftyJSON](https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON) and [Alamofire](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire) and you will find plenty of examples.

From Alamofire Readme:

```
Alamofire.request("https://httpbin.org/get").responseJSON { response in
debugPrint(response)

if let json = response.result.value {
    print("JSON: \(json)")
}}
```

From SwiftJSON Readme:

```
    let json = JSON(data: dataFromNetworking)
if let userName = json[0]["user"]["name"].string {
  //Your implementation here
}
```

You can also create a separate response object and deserialize all the response JSON into the object. Also take a look at the built-in `JSONSerialization` API in the `Foundation` framework.

Comment: Great, thank you. I read the documentation but I couldn't figure it out, now it's been separated up I understand it now!

Comment: Take a look at the ObjectMapper framework too. It gives you mappable objects which you can then use to serialize the response.